QT show the same content on multiple monitors
I have this kind of info app that is supposed to show some info content. It's written in QT / QML. Qt version is 5.12.
It runs on Raspberry Pi 4 - Lite image, no X, OpenGLES. Now what if I wanted to add another monitor that would display the same content. Just imagine the screen faces a different direction so that more people can see it.
I could probably try messing around with some HDMI splitters, but since RPi4 has two HDMI outputs, the idea is to use the other one.
What would be the easiest solution? I doubt I can just duplicate the screen without X, right? So I would probably need to implement it in the QT itself. In theory, I should be able to create more instances of the Window and set a different screen argument, but that sounds rather complicated as I would have to synchronize between all the instances. Can I somehow just display the same window twice?
Thanks for any suggestions.
Jan

If you don't have lots of animations and/or are not interested in extremely high performance, you may consider using QScreen::grabWindow on the source at regular intervals (35-40ms), then just use QLabels to display the content on the other screens.

I haven't used it but... on RPi5 there's a utility named raindrop. Not sure if it allows you to duplicate output but if anything does... –

@musicamante That sounds like an interesting idea. There are some animations, but they're not really essential, so it might work. Thanks for the tip.

@Aros You're welcome. In any case, if you find a solution that fits your needs, please consider clicking the "Answer your question" button and provide an appropriate answer that explains what you did and, possibly, a related [mre] of your approach.
